# Firebase: Data not submitting to database on certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two pages that need to submit to the database; a user registration page and a tire-input page. The user registration page works. The tire-input page does not. The tire page will show the alert inside the "submitClick()" but doesn't input anything into the database. If there is anymore information that you need, let me know. Thanks in advance.

I've tried working with the rules:

Current (letting the user-registration work, but not the tire-input)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not letting anything work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "Tires": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": true
   }
  }
}
```

HTML code (tire):

```
    <?php
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Emily-Projects/variables.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../inc/styles/css.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="content" style="background-color: white;">
        <div id="heading">
            <h1>Add A Tire<h1>
        </div>
        <form>
            <div id="1" class="form-sections">
                <div class="input-div">
                <label for="width" class="label">Width</label>
                <select name="width" id="width" type="select"  class="input">
                    <option value="">---</option>
                            <?php foreach ($tireWidths as $width) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $width;?>"><?php echo $width;?></option>
                            <?php } ?>

                </select></div>
                <div class="easy-div">
                    <div>
                                <?php foreach ($width100s as $width){ ?>
                                    <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $width;?>" class="width-sm"><?php echo $width?></z>
                                <?php } ?>

                                </div>
                            <div>
                                <?php foreach ($width200s as $width){ ?>
                                    <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $width;?>" class="width-sm"><?php echo $width?></z>
                                <?php } ?>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                        <?php foreach ($width300s as $width){ ?>
                                    <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $width;?>" class="width-sm"><?php echo $width?></z>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div> <!-- closing div#1-->
            <div id="2" class="form-sections">
                <div class="input-div">
                    <label for="aspect" class="label">Aspect Ratio</label>
                    <select class="input"  name="aspect" id="aspect">
                                <option value="">---</option>    
                        <?php foreach ($aspects as $aspect) {?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $aspect;?>"><?php echo $aspect;?></option>
                                    <?php   }?>

                            </select>
                </div>
                <div class="easy-div">
                    <div>
                                    <?php foreach ($aspectsTop as $a){ ?>
                                    <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $a;?>" class="aspectVal"><?php echo $a;?></z>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <?php foreach ($aspectsBottom as $a){ ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $a;?>" class="aspectVal"><?php echo $a;?></z>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                    </div>
        </div> <!-- closing div#2-->
            <div id="3" class="form-sections">
                <div class="input-div">
                    <label class="label" for="rim">Rim Diameter</label>
                    <select id="rim" name="rim" class="input">
                                <option value="">---</option>
                                <?php foreach ($rimDiameter as $rim){ ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $rim;?>"><?php echo $rim;?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                </div>
                <div class="easy-div">
                    <div>
                                <?php foreach ($rimDiaTop as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="rimVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                <?php foreach ($rimDiaBottom as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="rimVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- closing div#3-->
            <div id="4" class="form-sections">
                <div class="input-div">
                    <label class="label" for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                    <select class="input" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $m) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $m;?>"><?php echo $m;?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="easy-div">
                        <div id="manu-group-one">
                                <?php foreach ($manufacturersOne as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="manVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="manu-group-two">
                                <?php foreach ($manufacturersTwo as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="manVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="manu-group-three">
                                <?php foreach ($manufacturersThree as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="manVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="manu-group-four">
                                <?php foreach ($manufacturersFour as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="manVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="manu-group-five">
                                <?php foreach ($manufacturersFive as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="manVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="manu-group-six">
                                <?php foreach ($manufacturersSix as $r) { ?>
                                <z data-role="button" data-val="<?php echo $r;?>" class="manVal"><?php echo $r;?></z>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- closing div#4-->
            <div id="5" class="form-sections">
                <div id="5a" class="inner-B"><div class="input-div"><label class="label" for="model">Model</label>
                <select id="model" name="model"  class="input">
                    <option value="">---</option>   
                    <option value="test">Test</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="easy-div">EASY BUTTONS</div>
                </div><!--closing A -->

                <div id="5B" class="inner-A"><label class="label" for="weight">Shipping Weight</label><input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" class="input"></div><!--closing B -->
            </div> <!-- closing div#5-->
            <div id="6" class="form-sections">
                <div id="6A" class="inner-C">
                    <div class="input-div">
                        <label class="label" for="trim">Trim</label>
                        <select name="trim" id="trim" class="input" >
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <option value="test">Test</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="easy-div">EASY BUTTONS</div>
                </div><!--closing A -->
                <div id="6B" class="inner-D">
                    <label class="label" for="cost">Tire Cost</label>
                    <input name="cost" id="cost" class="input">
                </div><!--closing B -->
                <div id="6C" class="inner-E">PICTURES</div><!--closing C -->
            </div> <!-- closing div#6-->
            <div id="7" class="form-sections">
                <div id="7A" class="inner-D">
                    <div class="label">Run Flat?</div>
                    <div class="input"><input type="radio" name="runflat" value="yes"> Yes  <input type="radio" name="runflat" value="no"> No </div>
                </div><!--closing A -->
                <div id="7B" class="inner-F">
                    <div class="label">Tread Depth</div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" name="tread" id="tread" ><br><br>
                        <?php for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){ ?>
                            <z data-role="button" > <?php echo $i;?></z>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php for($i=11; $i<21; $i++){ ?>
                            <z data-role="button" > <?php echo $i;?></z>
                        <?php } ?>     <z data-role="button" >.25 </z>
                        <z data-role="button" >.5</z>
                        <z data-role="button" >.75</z>
                    </div>
                </div><!--closing B -->
                <div id="7C" class="inner-F"><div class="label">DOT Date</div><div class="input">INPUT</div></div><!--closing C -->
                <div id="7D" class="inner-F"><label class="label" for="patches">Number of Patches</label>
                <div class="input"><?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){?>
                    <z data-role="button" ><?php echo $i;?></z>
                    <?php
                }?></div></div> <!--closing D-->    
            </div> <!-- closing div#7-->
            <div id="8" class="form-sections">
                <div id="8A" class="inner-G"><div class="label">Retail Price</div>
                    <input type="text" id="retailPrice" name="retailPrice" class="input">
                </div>
                <div id="8B" class="inner-G"><div class="label">C.U.T. Share</div><div class="input">- $4.99 </div></div>
                <div id="8C" class="inner-G"><div class="label">C.C. Fee</div><div class="input"><?php echo $ccfee;?></div></div>
                <div id="8D" class="inner-G">Not Applicable</div>
                <div id="8E" class="inner-G"><div class="label">Shipping Est.</div><div class="input"><?php echo $shipEst;?></div></div>
                <div id="8F" class="inner-G"><div class="label">My Pay Out</div><div class="input"><?php echo $payOutRetail;?></div></div>
                <div id="8G" class="inner-G"><div class="label">Tire NOT listed on Cheapest Used Tires</div><div class="input">INPUT</div></div>

            </div> <!-- closing div#8-->
            <div id="9" class="form-sections">
                <div id="9A" class="inner-G"><div class="label">Wholesale Price</div>
                <input type="text" id="retailPrice" name="retailPrice" class="input"></div>
                <div id="9B" class="inner-G"><div class="label">C.U.T. Share</div><div class="input">- $4.99</div></div>
                <div id="9C" class="inner-G"><div class="label">C.C. Fee</div><div class="input"><?php echo $ccfee;?></div></div>
                <div id="9D" class="inner-G"><div class="label">Buyer&apos;s Bucks</div><div class="input">- $3.00</div></div>
                <div id="9E" class="inner-G"><div class="label">Shipping Est.</div><div class="input"><?php echo $shipEst;?></div></div>
                <div id="9F" class="inner-G"><div class="label">My Pay Out</div><div class="input"><?php echo $payOutWS;?></div></div>
                <div id="9G" class="inner-G"><div class="label">Wholesale ONLY</div><div class="input">INPUT</div></div>
            </div><!--closing div#9-->
        <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="submitClick()"value="Add This Tire">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- closing container -->

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="/Emily-Projects/new-add-a-tire.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tire JS:

```
 //File: new-add-a-tire.js

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCLpexd_9jOLjwcraume8RDXqag8mUSyMY",
    authDomain: "funoto-a67ec.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://funoto-a67ec.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "funoto-a67ec",
    storageBucket: "funoto-a67ec.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "270438905275"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


  //Add a Tire to Firbase

  var width = document.getElementById("width");
  var aspect = document.getElementById("aspect");
  var rim = document.getElementById("rim");
  var manufacturer = document.getElementById("manufacturer");

  var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
  //Function: submitClick();

  function submitClick(){

    window.alert("Works");

    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    firebaseRef.child("Tires").set("some value");
  }
```

Comment: try `.set("some value").then().catch()` to get any errors

Comment: I did : firebaseRef.child("Tires").set("some value").then().catch(); 
Where would I see the errors? Nothing pops up on the google dev console, and no error log is created in cPanel. The active page is:demo.mobilifytech.com/Emily-Projects/new-add-a-tire.php

Comment: `.catch(function(err){console.log(err)})`

Comment: Still getting nothing in the console.  And nothing goes to the database either.

Comment: try printing ref `console.log(firebaseRef)` and check you getting it correctly

Comment: It isn't staying up there, but it says something about "t repo"?

Comment: Does setting an object work {tire: round} ?

Comment: Where would I put that? I'm new to javascript as well.

Comment: I did .set("{tire: round}"); was that correct?

Comment: `.set({tire: "round"});`

Comment: Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I am following the official [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) try this

```
function submitClick(){

    window.alert("Works");

    var firebaseRef = firebase.database();
    firebaseRef.ref("Tires").set({tire: "round"});
}
```

Comment: Nothing, sorry. Is there something I need to do to the rules possibly?

Comment: your rule looks ok to me

Comment: also try `.push({tire: "round"})`

Comment: I have the top one (just the users). and the .push didn't do anything either.

Comment: does writing on database happen when you allow all permission `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}`

Comment: No. Nothing wrote to the database when I did that.

Comment: then you should recheck your firebase initialization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159649/discussion-between-ryder-thacker-and-hareesh).